# Word file saved to hard drive "not found"

Tags: data-recovery, microsoft-word-2007, hard-drive-recovery, file-recovery

I am using Word 2007. I modified a version of the file which was saved to my harddrive and saved my changes. When I wanted to open the file again, I went 'Recent Documents and clicked the file. However, I received an error message: "This file could not be found" which referenced the path to the file in the harddrive. When I checked the harddrive, indeed it was not there at all.

I am not sure why the file is not in the harddrive, and why my changes were not saved. I also checked that there was nothing in the AutoRecovery file.

Comment: Did you check your recycle bin?

Comment: @DavidPostill no its not in the recycle bin

Comment: Did you try a quick check with a tool like Recuva?